# Interval in which solution of DE exists

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with this Differential equation problem . Here is the problem 
*The solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}$$=y²$ , $y(0)=2$,$y \in[0,4]$,$x\in[-2,2]$ lies in what interval ??*

My try:- I tried to make use of *Picard's existence theorem* but I am not getting the interval . Then I found the solution of differential equation i.e.

$\frac{-1}{y}$$=$$x$$\frac{-1}{2}$ , I don't know how to get interval from here .

Any hints will be really appreciable.

Comment: Could you try to write the solution a little more readable? I get $y(x)=\frac2{1-2x}$ which has a clearly recognizable singularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I managed to solve my own problem .

On applying **uniqueness and existence theorem** here it is:-

**Given an initial value problem $y'=f(x,y)$ with $y(x_0)=(y_0)$**.

**$R$= $x_0-a<x<x_0+a  And  y_0-b<y<y_0+b$**

- $f(x,y)$ is continuous on$R$
- $f(x,y)$ is bounded on $R$ I.e. there is a $K$ such that $|f(x,y)|$ is less than equal to $K$
- $f_y$ is continuous on $R$
- $f_y$ is bounded on $R$

Then there exist unique solution in $|x-x_0|$$\leq$$\alpha$. Where $\alpha=min(a,b/k)$

On applying this theorem to the given problem

Clearly ,

- $f(x,y)=y²$ is continuous on $R$
- $f(x,y)=y²$  is bounded on $R$ and bound is $K=16$
- $f_y=2y$ exists on $R$
- $f_y$ is bounded on $R$

Than there is unique solution in $|x|$$\leq$ $\alpha$ where $\alpha = min(2,1/8)$

Hence the interval is $[-1/8,1/8]$

Comment: Your first bound is wrong, $y^2\le 16$ for $y\in[0,4]$, so that $b/K=\frac18$. The exact solution has a pole at $x=\frac12$, thus moves outside $R$ at an earlier point, at $x=\frac14$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me